# Dynamically loading pre-compiled views from an unreferenced assembly gives wrong error to main MVC app (doesn't recognize model Type)

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, plugins, .net-assembly

Hi guys this might be a tough one:

I currently am working on plugins for my MVC website, and I do the following:

1. Create a main MVC app
2. Create a plugin MVC app and build it into a .dll file with pre-compiled views (razor generator)
3. Fetch the plugin .dll assembly files into the main app
4. Use MEF to dynamically create a plugin controller, which calls the pre-compiled views.
5. Use the RazorGenerator MVC Engine to map routes and find the views in the .dll as well as load them
6. The pre-compiled view from the *unreferenced* plugin MVC app is displayed on-screen.

The problem is, it works 100% well with views which have no Models, but **whenever I attach a model to it, the main app doesn't seem to recognize the Namespace / Class of the model** and throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type 'PluginTest.Models.ProductModel', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'PluginTest.Models.ProductModel'

Full exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type 'PluginTest.Models.ProductModel', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'PluginTest.Models.ProductModel'. at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary
>   viewData) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.set_ViewData(ViewDataDictionary value) at
>   RazorGenerator.Mvc.PrecompiledMvcView.Render(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer) in
>   C:\Users\ACertainUser\Desktop\ACertainFolder\RazorGenerator\RazorGenerator.Mvc\PrecompiledMvcView.cs:line
>   81 at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)

This error usually means that the controller didn't send the right model to the view, but in this case, I think the main app doesn't know what this Type is.

It happens at this portion of the code (from RazorGenerator.Mvc):

```
public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
        {
            WebViewPage webViewPage = _viewPageActivator.Create(viewContext.Controller.ControllerContext, _type) as WebViewPage;

            if (webViewPage == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid view type");
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_masterPath))
            {
                _overriddenLayoutSetter.Value(webViewPage, _masterPath);
            }

            webViewPage.VirtualPath = _virtualPath;
            webViewPage.ViewContext = viewContext;

            webViewPage.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(viewContext.ViewData); // IT CRASHES HERE
            webViewPage.InitHelpers();

            WebPageRenderingBase startPage = null;

            if (this.RunViewStartPages)
            {
                startPage = StartPage.GetStartPage(webViewPage, "_ViewStart", ViewStartFileExtensions);
            }

            var pageContext = new WebPageContext(viewContext.HttpContext, webViewPage, null);
            webViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(pageContext, writer, startPage);
        }
```

Also, when I debug this method and look at the viewContext parameter, I see that the correct Model data is present (contains only 3 fields: id, name, cost). So that means the Model from the ViewContext is legit, instanciated and has correct data in it. It just does not seem to like being transported over to the webViewPage.ViewData dictionary. Keep in mind I'm debugging the main app and yet I have visibility over a class from a different assembly.

http://prntscr.com/igksd1

Is there any way for me to fix this issue, so I can have working Models from an unreferenced Assembly?

Huge thanks!

EDIT: Could reflection maybe solve this? How could I import a type from another assembly so the WebViewPage object could see it when trying to copy the dictionary data?

Comment: Where do you have defined the model type?

Comment: You may be loading twice the library, I had those types of error with dynamic load when you have two files of the same library, one is loaded by the system automatically and other is loaded by you.

Comment: It's inside the plugin .dll, which is an assembly containing a complete MVC project (so it has controllers, models and views). Controllers are found via MEF, and views via RazorGenerator. Model types, however, don't seem to have any visibility inside the main app (even though I can look at them while debugging).

Comment: Yeah, thought it'd be too tough :(